# No able to understand sentry exception report

Tags: ios, sentry

I have an app published on Apple App Store.

I have created a Sentry project to track the app.

Now I have an exception breakpoint issue reported on Sentry, but all the given information is completely not understable.
Therefore I have downloaded the appDsyms.zip file from iTunesConnect and uploaded it to Sentry using the sentry-cli client.

What are the next steps to do to get a much clearer description from the issue?

I am not able to find a tutorial about translating the Sentry information of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you upload the symbols, any incoming crash or error should show symbolicated frames automatically. There's nothing else you need to do to enable that.

[Sentry has some docs on the upload process](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/apple/guides/ios/dsym/), ideally it would be automated so these are uploaded before your app goes live.